# Dell Monitor not working after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, lts, nvidia-geforce

I have a Dell Monitor(P2317H) connected to my notebook Dell Inspiron(15700) by HDMI port using Ubuntu 16.04LTS version and after Ubuntu upgrade the monitor is not recognized anymore. I'm using NVIDIA driver 384.69 and I also tried others versions but with no success. Before upgrade everything was working fine, the problem is that I don't remember what drivers, packages I was using :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the last update everything works fine, I don't know what was the problem because I still have NVIDIA driver 384.69.